# Start without any sound?

Tags: sound, mute

How can you disable the startup-sound? I mean the drums when you login.
Edit: I have tried disabling Gnome Login Sound, but it keeps drumming.

And also set the volume to muted so that it sticks? Now when I press mute on keyboard the first keypress seems to lower the volume instead, and thus plays a sound. Second keypress works.

I would like to start without any sound at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just log out, then click on the little speaker icon in the upper right hand corner of the login screen.  Set the volume here to Mute.